# How to display story points on cards on GreenHopper Kanban?

Tags: jira, scrum, jira-plugin, kanban, jira-agile

I'm considering switching from scrum to Kanban template on JIRA GreenHopper.

user Story Cards on kanban style work mode does not show user points :

[image]

How can I change it to this :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Javascript solution to display storypoints on the Scrum/Kanban boards.

The script is attached to [this](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-6755) jira issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're not the first to ask for this - there's an outstanding feature request with Atlassian: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-7265. I suggest anyone who stumbles across this question adds their vote to the request - perhaps one day we'll get it!

Answer (score 0):

No easy way, though you can change the card color based on a JQL query on a Story Points or another custom field